# What do I need to move the gas line and regulator closer to the ceiling?

Tags: gas, regulator

I want to insert a wall oven in this cabinet and the gas line and gas regulator are in the way. How can I move it closer to the ceiling ? What cable and connector should I get ?

Thank you.

Quick Update :

I was able to move the regulator with the help of a handy man (See last picture). It's all good now. I will access the shut off valve from the room behind to respect the building code.
And now I can slide my electric wall oven !

Thanks everyone for the help!!

[image: underside of counter top range]

[image: counter top range showing empty cabinet space beneath]

[image: another perspective of underside of counter top range]

[image]

Comment: can you install the elbow facing upwards or install the regulator without the elbow?

Comment: It looks like you don’t have any space can it be recessed in the wall? Usually regulators can not be enclosed but can be in small alcoves in the wall, hard to tell if there are any other options.

Comment: gas is the least diy service, often illegal's to touch except with licensed plumbers. Considering the complications you face, might want to "outsource" this one to a pro.

Comment: @Jasen, I tried to lift the elbow a bit but it's not enough. Also It seems there may not have enough space for the regulator without the elbow.

Comment: @EdBeal I added more pictures. I don't think I have much option here. Perhaps access it from the room behind, or run everything under the cabinet ?

Comment: @dandavis, I hear you. Trying to assess what needs to be done and then I will make a decision. Leaning towards calling a pro, if I cannot access the shutoff valve from the other room (behind the wall).

Comment: maybe you can move  the regulator to  the other end of the hose?  I'm not sure if that is allowed.

Comment: Yes ! Great idea @Jasen ! Greg suggested it as well yesterday. I am leaning towards that with opening bedroom wall if I go full DIY.

Comment: There may be some rules about how close the valve has to be to the appliance check your locations's gas plumbing code.

Comment: Thanks for the additional photos! Yes as i suggested the regulator moved into the wall space is a possibility, the shutoff has to be accessible but from ? Not specified in code at least in my jurisdiction. My jurisdiction allows a home owner to do almost everything (shock they can not inspect the work !)  just a comment

Comment: @Jasen, ok will check the plumbing code. Thank you.

Comment: @EdBeal, Nice ! Good to know :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my mind installation of a wall oven is a "permanent" kind of thing. There is a shutoff valve in the hole in the wall; permanently installing a wall oven in this cabinet space will render that valve inaccessible. That's "Not Good" -- you may need to relocate the valve so that it remains accessible after the new oven is installed. When you find a good place for the shutoff valve you may also find there's room for the regulator to be installed there rather than here.

Depending on what's on the other side of this wall it might be reasonable to cut a new access hole on that side. The hole could be covered with a removable "plumbing access panel" to make it look a little better. Providing access to the valve in this way eliminates the need to move the valve.

Edit after addition of photos from different perspective:

Now seeing that you're thinking of a wall oven beneath a cooktop... have you considered cutting out the cabinet entirely and using a slide-in range? That would be pretty easy if you can get one in a width that fits!

It looks like you have another cabinet to the right of the one in question. I'd consider extending the hard gas pipe into there, put a shutoff valve in that space, then take the flex appliance connector back into the first cabinet. Or cut an access hole between the two cabinets and position the shutoff valve(s) in the left cabinet where they can be reached through the access hole. Probably do 2x valves and connector so that the cooktop and oven are valved separately.

Either way, install the regulator somewhere along the way wherever it's convenient. Ensure the regulator has enough capacity for the two appliances or get another regulator.

Comment: Thx a lot Greg. I didn't think about the valve not being accessible indeed. That's a bummer. Behind the wall is the bedroom. I may be able to do smth. Let me see. I gonna upload more pictures tonight.

Comment: Pictures added!

Comment: Thx @Greg! I thought about the slide-in range but opted it out : I will have to cut my beautiful countertop but also cut the bottom of the cabinet and redo the joint with caulk. I am too lazy to do all of that. Also, I like the design of my stove and my countertop and don't really want to change it.
Btw, I am going for an electric wall oven that goes for $450. Would be efficient financially and esthetically. So no need to split the gas. Gas will stay connected only to the stove. Oven will be plugged to the electrical outlet :-D

Comment: Do you mean the 20A duplex? I find it hard to believe you can get a really good oven running off just 20A 120V. That's toaster oven territory...

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact A small steam or convection oven, maybe? I use convection bake in my over-the-range convection/microwave oven for baking more often than I use the full-size 30" slide-in oven; it gets along fine on the 20A/120V.. even if it is only slightly more than just a fancy built-in toaster oven. :-)

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Wall oven is 220V actually. I found a 110V to 220V converter/transformer for $100.

Comment: How much power does the oven need? Aside from "transformer with a high enough rating", there is a big problem that the current rating (of circuit/breaker/wire) will have to be larger for a 120V circuit than it would for a 240V circuit. If the oven needs 20A (which is low) @ 240V, it will need 40A @ 120V - and your existing wiring will *not* support that. If the oven is actually gas (I thought only the cooktop was gas here...) then it probably only needs a couple Amps for controls/igniter and transformer is OK.

Comment: Oven is the Empava 24-in Single Electric Wall Oven (available at lowes or Home Depot). Specifications says : 2000 Watts, 240 Volts/60hz, 20 amps breaker required. My wiring is 20A.

Comment: @Lou It won't meet code, and also probably won't work, to power this oven via a transformer from a 120 V 20 A circuit. We can explain why not, and help explore options to get you where you want to go, if you'll ask a new question about it. That'll work much better than attempting to address it in a chain of comments ever could. :-)

Comment: @GregHill oh ok. Alright, I'll create a new question. Thanks for the info.